# Ethernet Ubuntu to Raspberry Pi

Tags: 15.10, ethernet, raspberrypi

Why am i not able to connect my ubuntu to raspberry p via ethernet.The ethernet status keeps on saying connecting..and never connects.
It connects in windows 10.

Comment: Can you add details how your systems are set up and how do you try to connect?

Comment: I connected the Ethernet cable and the pi. When I go to network settings.. It just says connecting..

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same situation and I resolved it by plugging an higher capacity microUSB power supply.

The one I had clearly said 5V 2A but it so happens that a better quality 5V 2A really provided 2A while the cheap one that came with the Pi kit didn't live up to the task.

Try that and keep me posted please.

Best regards.

Marc.

Comment: Hey Marc! I have mentioned in the question that things work fine with Windows 10, so I suppose that would make power supply unlikely right? Let me know if you have any other suggestions :)

Comment: Hi again. IoT certainly does not use all the same components in all the same way. Nor does it draw power the same way. To better disprove (or prove) my answer, could you try burning openElec on a spare SD card ans see if you have the multicolored square (undervoltage) on the top right of the screen? If so, then it proves my affirmation. IoT and other OSes don't "play" the same on the very same hardware.

Comment: Will powering the pi through my laptop be sufficient?

Comment: no it will not. You can barely get 300 mA from a laptop USB port. Sorry!

Comment: Alright.. I will try changing the power adapter and let you know.. Even mine says 2A but might be faulty!

Comment: Thanks Sridhar. You'd be surprised to see how MANY posts in Pi forums on ubuntu mate, raspbian, opelelec and osmc end up in power supply replacement solving the problem. I sincerely wish that solves it for you.